# How to set width in MenuItem material-ui

Tags: reactjs, select, material-ui, menuitem

I'm just starting my adventure with react. I tried to use select with material-ui, but now I run into a wall. My select has a certain width and when MenuItem has a short content then the dropdown section has the same width. The problem is when one of the options has very long content. Then the dropdown section overlaps the side menu and extends beyond its area.
How can I fix it?

```
<Select
   name="reason"
   tyle={{ marginTop: "0px" }}
>
{
  data.map((el) => {
  return (
    <MenuItem
      value={el.description}
      key={el.name}
    >
      <span>
        {el.description}
      </span>
    </MenuItem>
    );
  })
}
</Select>
```

Comment: In short, your `SELECT` width is determined by the largest `MenuItem` in your list.  You have many options ..  Here's just a few: 1) if `{el.description}` is too long, trim it in it's `<span>` with [text-overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow).  2) you could use JS to shorten `{el.description}` as to not interfere with the width of your element.  3) you can wrap your text so that it falls on the next line -- Essentially taking up 2 "spots".  There is a ton you can do here.

Comment: You should also edit your question with [WHAT YOU HAVE TRIED](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)